# Sublime Text 3 Packages folder has unusual contents

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I think I'm going mad.

Apparently all of my installed packages and themes should be in

`/Users/Nathan/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3`

However the contents of that folder are… odd. A few random packages Including one I didn't know I'd installed) and an empty `Theme - Default` folder. I have many packages installed that are not in that folder.

[image]

This is also the folder that's opened when I choose 'Browse Packages' from the settings menu.

So um, where are all my packages/themes? Is there any alternative directory?

Answer (score 1):

The packages I have installed are located are in an 'Installed Packages' directory, I would guess for you it's located at:

```
/Users/Nathan/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
```

I just have bz2 and User located in my Sublime Text 3 directory.

Also, from the docs:

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/packages.html

> Zipped packages may be stored in:
>
> `executable_path>/Packages`
>   `<data_path>/Installed Packages`
>
> Loose packages may be stored in:
>
> `<data_path>/Packages`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hm, yes, thanks, that folder does seem to have the sublime-package files in it. However none of the color schemes are in it (they're supposed to be in that folder I screen-capped, apparently, but they're clearly not). I was trying to track down a color scheme to make a small change, the last time I did this I'm sure I remember it being much easier! :p

Comment: I've just checked on my macbook (which has only ever had ST3 on it, the screencap above is from my imac which upgraded from 2 to 3) - and interestingly there is no mention *at all* of themes or color schemes in the packages or installed packages folders. They must be somewhere! (and clearly not where they're supposed to be)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you install the [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) package which lets you view files/folders from your installed packages and also lets you extract your installed packages and make them show up in your actual Packages folder.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - that's at least got me where I needed to be!

Comment: Np. If you ever want to edit a file that is in a package, like a color scheme file, you can just use `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` and if you ever want to extract the entire package into your *Packages* folder, you can just use `PackageResourceViewer: Extract Package`. You will then be able to see the package in your *Packages* folder.